# Symfony Doctrine One to Many andX query builder

Tags: doctrine, query-builder

I have an entity of Product that has OneToMany AttributeValues. Each AttributeValue, has an Attribute relationship and a "value" parameter.

I want to filter through the Products that have in the same time let's say "color"(Attribute)  "black"(value) and "size" "2m".

```
        $qb->leftJoin("product.attrVal","attrVal");
        $andX = $qb->expr()->andX();
        $count = 0;
        foreach($params['filters'] as $att_id => $values) {
            foreach ($values as $val){
                $andX->add("attrVal.attribute = :att_id_".$count." and attrVal.value = :val_".$count);
                $qb->setParameter("att_id_".$count, $att_id);
                $qb->setParameter("val_".$count, $val);
                $count++;
            }

        }
        $qb->andWhere($andX);
```

Of course this is only working if only one attribute is given. If the filters array contains more than one value it gives no results. Probably because it's looking to satisfy all criteria on the same AttributeValue object and not looking for all AttributeValue objects that satisfy at  least one criteria. But my final goal is to find objects that have all the given attributes at once. But can't figure out how to state that in the query builder.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. Maybe it's not the best one but it works.

I begin by innerJoining my attributes and counting them.

```
    $qb->from($this->_entityName, 'product')    
    $qb->addSelect('product')    
    $qb->innerJoin("product.attributes","attributes");
    $qb->addSelect('COUNT(attributes.id) AS attributesCount');
    $qb->groupBy('product.id');
```

Then I add an orX instead of andX, to get all the products that have at least one of the attributes.

```
    $orX = $qb->expr()->orX();
    $count = 0;
    foreach($params['filters'] as $att_id => $values) {
        foreach ($values as $val){
            $orX->add("attributes.attribute = :att_id_".$count." and attributes.value = :val_".$count);
            $qb->setParameter("att_id_".$count, $att_id);
            $qb->setParameter("val_".$count, $val);
            $count++;
        }

    }
    $qb->andWhere($orX);
```

Finally I make sure to return only the values that count all the defined attributes. To filter out the products that don't have all the attributes.

```
    $qb->having("attributesCount = :ac");
    $qb->setParameter("ac", $count);
```